# How to insert mathematical symbols like Greek characters in a Graphviz dot file?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have an unique problem. I am using dot to represent a graph which is generic in nature. So, instead of using numbers, I was planning to use symbols like greek letters like alpha, beta, etc. I am curious to know how can we label nodes/edges in .dot file using some symbols?

for example,

```
node1 -> node2 [label= <something here which will show up as symbol of beta> style=dashed]
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use HTML-like a labels:

```
digraph G {
  a [ label=<&#945;>]
  b [ label=<&#946;>]
  c [ label=<&#947;>]

  a -> b -> c
}
```

will show `alpha -> beta -> gamma`:

[image]

You could also used named HTML references to make it even clearer (mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684807/how-can-one-insert-a-mathematical-greek-etc-symbol-in-dot-file/41346289#comment21724438_9686336)):

```
label=<I love &alpha; and &beta;>
```

The surrounding `<>` indicate that the label should be parsed as a custom language that looks like an HTML subset: http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html#html

Comment: Even cleaner: `label="I love &alpha; and &beta;"`

Comment: @Tarrasch I didn't knew that you could use these named variants as well. Good to know.

Comment: I get this error with HTML-like:

```
Error: not well-formed (invalid token) in line 1
... <HTML>&##945; ...
```

Comment: Works fine, but how can one use this inside a node record?`label=<&#945;|&#946>` doesn't work :((

Answer (score 4):

**Unicode characters**

Sometimes you can get away with Unicode https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet#Greek_in_Unicode

```
graph {
    "α" -- "β"
}
```

Output:

[image]

You can also emulate some more math with Unicode, e.g.:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode

Tested on Ubuntu 16.10, graphviz 2.38.